# Iterative procedure with nested loops in functional paradigm

Tags: c++, loops, haskell, functional-programming, iteration

I'm learning functional programming (in Haskell) by re-writing some of my old C++ code. One example I'm working on involves the Floyd-Warshall graph search which runs on a 2D NxN adjacency matrix to find the shortest path between all pairs. It uses three nested for loops to scan the 2D array and iteratively reach a solution.

The C++ code would typically be:

```
int size = adjacencyMatrix.size();
for ( int k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            double sum = adjacencyMatrix[i][k] + adjacencyMatrix[k][j];
            if ( sum < adjacencyMatrix[i][j] )
            {
                    adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key to such a graph search is its iterative method. For example the code above is very sequential; it can only be parallelised to a moderate extent as some calculations can't be done till others have completed.

Furthermore, having access to the index of the matrix means some clever manipulations within the array can be done. The innermost loop of the above graph search uses `adjacencyMatrix[i][k]`, `adjacencyMatrix[k][j]` and `adjacencyMatrix[i][j]`. I'm aware of the `map` function in Haskell, but that doesn't seem to have the same power and flexibility as using array indices.

Aside from trying to simulate an imperative procedure in Haskell I can't work out how re-write the above code in a 'pure' functional style.

How does an iterative procedure that uses complex nested loops to access array indices, such as the graph search above, translate to the functional paradigm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Aside from trying to simulate an imperative procedure in Haskell I can't work out how re-write the above code in a 'pure' functional style.

I'm not sure you *can* always rewrite a fundamentally imperative algorithm in a functional style. That said, here's how one would translate your example in Haskell. Note that in general, whenever you find yourself really needing to have mutable variables for a bit, you probably want to use the [`ST` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html). For arrays, you have the efficient [`array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.1/docs/Data-Array.html) package.

Here's what a full translation of that algorithm can look like

```hs
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newListArray, readArray, writeArray)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.Foldable (for_)

-- | Takes as input the number of vertices, function to weigh edges, and returns
-- a matrix of the shortest distance between every two vertices.
floydWarshall :: Int -> ((Int,Int) -> Maybe Double) -> UArray (Int,Int) Double
floydWarshall n weight = runSTUArray $ do
    -- initialize the array with the right values
    arr <- newListArray ((0,0),(n-1,n-1))
                        [ if i == j then 0 else fromMaybe (1 / 0) (weight (i,j))
                        | i<-[0..(n-1)], j<-[0..(n-1)] ]

    -- iteratively improve the shortest distances
    for_ [0..(n-1)] $ \k ->
      for_ [0..(n-1)] $ \i ->
        for_ [0..(n-1)] $ \j -> do
          arr_ik <- readArray arr (i,k)
          arr_kj <- readArray arr (k,j)
          arr_ij <- readArray arr (i,j)
          let sum = arr_ik + arr_kj
          when (sum < arr_ij)
            (writeArray arr (i,j) sum)

    return arr
```

Comment: @Antisthenes Is it? Maybe. For an algorithm as sequential as Floyd-Warshall, I actually find the above more readable than map's and fold's - regardless of the fact that I also have some hard guarantees on the time/space usage (notice that output is an _unboxed_ array). Also, `arrays` expresses multi-dimensional arrays much more clearly than nested vectors or lists.

Comment: It surely is more efficient than using functional approach, however this slightly misses the point of using Haskell in first place.

Comment: Keep in mind that `for` will construct a list of return values, only for it to be thrown away.  [`forM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_) exists specifically because this has a cost.

Comment: @luqui I'm slowly phasing out `Control.Monad.forM_` in favor of `Data.Foldable.for_` in my new code.

Comment: @chi Thanks! I keep forgetting about `for_`. @luqui Good advice - IIRC there is (was?) a recent issue about GHC performing significantly worse with `forM` (as compared to `forM_`).

Comment: @Antisthenes I don't really agree. One of the nice things about Haskell is that you *can* do stuff like this, when it's the clearest way to get something done. You can opt into whatever monads will simplify your problem space, rather than being stuck with the same approach to every problem.

Answer (score 4):

The best option is to use Data.Vector package and use ifoldl with nested imaps which will look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import Data.Vector

type Matrix a = Vector (Vector a)

floydwarshall mat = ifoldl (\m k _ ->
                               imap (\i row ->
                                       imap (\j v -> 
                                               (m!i!k + m!k!j) `min` v) row) m) mat mat
```

Ifoldl and imap alongside values stored inside vector maps using their indices, which allows you to call values at specific index. The foldl is needed to accumulate all the changes in iterations of k while keeping structure immutable. Inside of imaps you must index inside matrix m which is our accumulator for foldr and which keeps all changes.

If you don't want to import packages, you may always implement imap and ifoldl for stock prelude lists

```
imap :: (Int -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
imap f = map (uncurry f) . zip [0,1..]

ifoldl :: (b -> Int -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
ifoldl f acc = foldl (\ac -> uncurry (f ac)) acc . zip [0,1..]
```

EDITED: According to suggestion by @chi

Comment: Although this could in theory be optimized to one mutable vector, this solution runs the risk of allocating quite a bit of space.

Comment: It's true, that in production it should be profiled for memory usage, however it was specified, that question is about writing it "purely functional style", which i did in my answer. Of course it may choke on very big matrices however this often is the case when using "purely functional style" with purely functional, immutable data structures.

Comment: Also consider ``imap (\j v -> (m!i!k + m!k!j) `min` v)``